# Partition table without Incremental Update Statistics

Tags: sql-server

Do I have to enable incremental update statistics when I want to have partitions on my table? Are there any automatic mechanisms  that will update statistics on my table utomatically?

Answer (score 0):

From [SQL Server Auto Update and Auto Create Statistics Options](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2766/sql-server-auto-update-and-auto-create-statistics-options/)

- The statistics are automatically created for each new index.
- If the    database setting AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS is on, then the SQL
  Server    will automatically create statistics for non-indexed
  columns that are    used in your queries.